# Change background of a grouped UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm having some trouble trying to change the background of a UITableView with groups.

```
_tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableViewBg.png"]];
```

This usually works on every other UITableView, but not the one with groups, is there something else I have to do?
In IB I have the background color set to a clear color, but that doesn't do much.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You additionally need to disable the background view of `_tableView`:

```
[_tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
 _tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

No need to add new view to backgroundView. This is working for me in `iOS6`.

Comment: great ans saved times.

Comment: Genius. Who knew that the grouped section headers were clear! As of whatever iOS we're at now in 2017, you don't need to nil out the background of the tableView. I just set it directly as white and that's all she wrote. Thanks for helping me sort this out!

Comment: @MikeCritchley this answer is given in 2013 as this wasn't implemented that time.

Answer (score 5):

why don't you set the tableView.backgroundView? you can alloc an image view withe the specified image and pass it to the background view instead of setting the background color.

Comment: Isn't the tableView.backgroundColor there to change the background color? Using tableView.backgroundView seems like a long workaround

Comment: Actually your answer helped me, turns out why you group a UITableView, the backgroundView is set, by using self.tableView.backgroundView = nil; you remove it

Answer (score 3):

What I usually do with grouped UITableViews is set the background color to clear, and the set that pattern image to the parents view.

```
self.parentViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableBG.png"]];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: I did try that too, but without any success: self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableViewBg.png"]];
    _tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: If I remember correctly the UITableView have a scroll view background.. Try this.. added to my answer.

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't do much too, I don't understand why it wont work here, in any other table i used the same code works fine

Comment: +1 this worked well for me, especially if I set backgroundview to nil.

Answer (score 1):

```
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: xxx];
// tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];  // is ok
```

if you set set the backgroundColor as this, when you scroll the tableView, the backgroundColor view will scroll also. so, you can: tableView.backgroundView = nil;  self.view.backgroundColor = ...

Answer (score 1):

The selected answer works but it clears the background of both tableHeaderView and table section header view. If you just want table header to be of a certain color say white and section header still to be default grey than do the following -

```
tableView.tableHeaderView.inputView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to add to Nirav's answer - it can also be done using the iOS 5 appearance proxy.

```
[[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundView:nil];
[[UITableView appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGreyColor]];
```

The advantage is that it is applies globally, so you can group all your UI customisations in one place.  However, it will apply to all tableViews (not just grouped style).

Answer (score 0):

For **iOS 9+**, changing the background color of the `UITableView` is enough.

**Objective-C**

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

**Swift**

```
tableView.backgroundColor = .red
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

> > **TO REMOVE BACKGROUND VIEW & COLOR**

```
tableView.backgroundView = nil
tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
```