# Set background color on UITableView in IOS 6

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, ios6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change background of a grouped UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11047029/change-background-of-a-grouped-uitableview)

I am not able to change the background color of UITableView if it is `UITableViewStyleGrouped`.
My code :

`[addressNewTbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];`

Help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack. If you got your answer then you should to accept that answer...

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You might need to add some code.
Try -

`[UITableView setBackgroundView: nil];`

or you can also do :

```
UIView* bview = [[UIView alloc] init];
bview.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[tableView setBackgroundView:bview];
```

Both will work..

Comment: Yes. the second one will work for backward compatibility also

Comment: When you group a UITableView, the backgroundView is set, by using self.tableView.backgroundView = nil; you remove it

Answer (score 6):

Did you try

```
addressNewTbl.backgroundView = nil;
[addressNewTbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You additionally need to disable the background view:

```
[addressNewTbl setBackgroundView:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the background color of the entire `UITableView`, try what happens when you set its `backgroundView`'s background color.

Answer (score -3):

in cellForRowAtIndexPath datasource method.try setting

```
[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIcolor redColor]];
```

Comment: OP is about table's background not cell's background..