# UITableView Background Color Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm looking to change the color for the background of my UITableView using Swift. I want to make both the cell background as well as the actual table's background a specific color. So far I have created a simple table with this code:

```swift
import UIKit

class MyTripsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Test"
        return cell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617913/set-background-color-on-uitableview-in-ios-6 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cell property `backgroundColor` changes background color. To setup color:

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.1, green: 0.2, blue: 0.3, alpha: 1.5)
```

Or use predefined colors:

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

Comment: That would help change the color of the cells, however would that also change the color of the table behind the cells? I want to change the color so that even areas within the table that don't have cells are that other color.

Comment: The same thing with tableView. `self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()`